# where this background come from

Tags: texturing, lighting, hdri, world

I have download one model from web, when in texture view, there shows a background which seems in a factory house. but I have turned all objects off, see attached picture.
if in render view, no such background.
what is this? how can I find it out? how can I change/replace it etc?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background is an HDR that is in the world lighting settings.  If you open the shader editor and go to world mode you'll see something like this:

[image: world shader]

perhaps without some of the nodes.  The block with the orange header is an *Image Texture*.  It is the source of the garage image in your case.